# Font import fallback for Emails

Tags: html, email, fonts, html-email

I hope this is no duplicate, I couldn't find anything similar.

I don't want the basic font fall back like: `font-family: "Poppins", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;`

I want a fallback for the import.
 So I have something like this in the `<head>` of my email so if one method isn't supported by the email client, it takes the next one (so far my idea).

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Poppins-Regular'), url(myFontUrl) format('woff');
}

@import url('myFontUrl');

</style>

<link href="myFontUrl" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This might be redundant but would it work like I want it to? If `@font-face` isn't supported use `@import` and so on. Or would I run into other problems I don't see now?

Comment: If you use the @font-face method, many MSO clients will fallback to Times New Roman, so you would want a workaround in place for that as well. More on emails and web fonts in [this Litmus article](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts/)

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't think it'll make a huge difference.
Email clients specifically block web font use for security reasons, as opposed to your method of accessing the font URL.

So no matter the method of import and going by the code you've posted, it's more likely an email client will block the web font and will load one of a list of pre-defined safe fonts which you can set as a fallback.

In reference to statements like this:

> I don't want the basic font fall back like: font-family: "Poppins", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;

... You don't really have a choice on what an email client chooses to load or not if it specifically blocks web fonts.

But just in case there is an issue with an email client that supports web fonts - it could help if you can state which email clients you aren't seeing your font load in and then we can help check if it's a font issue or an email client blocking issue.

Comment: Thanks. I know that I need the fallback. I just wrote that to make clear that I'm not talking about this kind of fallback

Answer (score 0):

Using `@import` is not going to help your cause, because that just loads another stylesheet that still has to use `@font-face`. The `<link>` tag suffers the same fate.

So using `@font-face` is the most robust way forward in terms of how to load a web font.

Only a few email clients support this (see https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/), namely Apple Mail, Outlook on MacOS, Outlook iOS (early versions only), Samsung app, Thunderbird and some less popular webmails.

To be compatible with Outlook on Windows, you need to add a websafe font using `mso-font-alt` like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  mso-font-alt: 'Arial';
}
```

So if you added another `@font-face` (including via `@import` or `<link>`) and you add that to the font-family, you aren't adding anything.

You do need to be aware that some font formats (like woff, ttf, otf) are supported in some environments, and some aren't. I haven't tested their support but I believe woff2 as used by Google Fonts works on all the above, so you shouldn't need to worry about that. If you do have an alternative format, you can add it in too like so: `url('proximanova-regitalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('proximanova-regitalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype')`

However, Gmail is different. Gmail supports only Roboto and Google/Open Sans. So you can add one of them to your font stack if you like. I.e. `font-family: "Poppins", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;`

Answer (score 0):

Like many StackOverflow responses, half the reason for this one is to remind myself that webfonts with email is pretty much a cul-de-sac. canIemail.com is a great resources, and I've taken screen shots of the three relevant techniques, so that the comparison is clear. I've omitted Apple Mail, as that works with everything (pretty much).
[image: canIemail screenshot compilation]

It is worthwhile doing some research about the system fonts that will be "web safe" across macos and Windows. For example, Rockwell has become more common on macos now, which provides a decent serif font with a relatively large x-height.